# Declaring a constant in a function

Tags: javascript, performance

I wonder if there's any performance difference between

```
var DATA = {a: 1, b: 2, ....};

function f() {
    ... use but do not modify DATA;
}
```

and

```
function f() {
    var DATA = {a: 1, b: 2, ....};
    ... use but do not modify DATA;
}
```

in a modern Javascript engine. In theory, in the latter code, the structure has to be created on every function invocation. But the engine can see it doesn't get changed and keep it for reuse.

I'm perfectly aware about the premature optimizations trap and readability being more important than performance; I'm just curious. As jsperf is down, I see no easy way to get some figures myself.

#### Update

Given this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m9cTaYI95Zc), it looks like at least V8 can do Copy On Write, so it's probably free in most modern browsers.

Given how modern JS engines work, it's rather futile to benchmarks such things manually and please *don't recommend it to anyone.* Many optimizations kick in after a few iterations, then some more profiling may happen, dead code elimination, etc. I don't know whether jsperf (which is sort of up ATM) does it all right, but doing it manually is non-sense (compare [this list of java benchmarking gotchas](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/architect-benchmarking.html)).

Comment: I don't get it. jsPerf is down, so ask StackOverflow to do it for you? Or are you asking how to performance test without jsPerf? Just not sure what you're after. Seems off topic.

Comment: Downvoters, please explain what's wrong with this question! Is asking about JS performance forbidden or what?

Comment: The developer tools have a `console.time/console.timeEnd` pair that are useful. People usually just do the typical loop of `n` iterations to get a better read on the difference. `console.time("foo"); /* do work */ console.timeEnd("foo");` Not perfect, but then this doesn't seem critical.

Answer (score 0):

There would be a performance difference in comparison. And when you compare the timeline of both. We will observe that function with local variable works fast. No matter how many times you called the function with the local variable, the performance would win in second type.